# boto3 How to install cloud watch agent using AWS SSM service through python script

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm

I'm trying to install cloud watch agent on multiple ec2 instances and then configure memory metrics on those instances.I was able to do it manually by following this [link](https://greencircle.vmturbo.com/docs/DOC-5444-setting-up-cloudwatch-memory-metrics-on-linux-instances-on-aws). But I have around 100+ ec2 instances in different regions and hence i'm planning to automate this using python boto3 package. Following is the code I'm trying

```
import boto3
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
try:
    ssm_resp = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=["i-0bb7f627b65157a5b"],
        DocumentName="AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage",
        Parameters={'action': ['install'], 'name': ['AmazonCloudWatchAgent']},
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Following is the error I'm getting when the above code is executed.
`An error occurred (InvalidParameters) when calling the SendCommand operation`:
I'm not sure what is error parameter, I have followed the documentation but I'm unclear which parameter is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be as simple as not using uppercase 'I' in install, but that's just a guess as I've not used this particular command. That and single vs double quotes which may or may not have an impact as well. I have had errors where some ec2 instances created from amis don't have ssm installed and that throws an error as well, but I don't think it was InvalidParameters.

Looking at the command line docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/distributor-working-with-packages-deploy.html

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage" \
    --instance-ids "i-00000000000000" \
    --parameters '{"action":["Install"],"installationType":["Uninstall and reinstall"],"name":["ExamplePackage"]}'
```